# Float value changing while inserting via c# to db with servicestack ormlite

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

The value of a float variable while selecting from database 1.67 but if I insert the same value to the database with servicestack ormlite it turns to 1.66999995708466.

There is no processing taking place in between select and insert. The datatype is float in application as well as database.

Comment: use `decimal` maybe?

Comment: It is working fine with decimal.  But i need to know the issue with float.

Comment: You may read about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)

Comment: 1.67 is just a prettified version of 1.6999… as floats use a base-2 number system and is limited to 7 digits of precision which can't precisely express a number like 1.67. (Likewise in base-10 you can't precisely print 1/3 with just n digits precision). If you would do `1.67.ToString("R")` you will see that 1.67 isn't actually 1.67.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floats are an imprecise data type, see the https://floating-point-gui.de (and its linked [detailed white paper](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)) for an explanation of the issue with floating point data types like .NET's `double` or `float`.

If you need perfect precision you can use .NET's `decimal` data type which doesn't have rounding errors or if you only need 2 decimal precision it's also common to use `int` to capture cents, e.g.

```
100 == 100 cents == $1
```